# How to understand "sat by the hour" in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> They **sat by the hour** eating anything they could spear on a toasting fork -- bread, English muffins, marshmallows -- and plotting ways of getting Malfoy expelled, which were fun to talk about even if they wouldn't work.

I'm not sure what exact "**sat by the hour**" means in this sentence. As I know, "*by the hour*" means *per hour* or *once a hour*. But I have a hard time to understand "sat by the hour" in this context. Is it *the time they sat there is counted by the hour* or *they would sit there for a while every hour*?

-- excerpted from Harry Potter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the expression "by the hour" means "continuously; over a period of some hours".

> by the hour
>
> by the hour/from hour to hour continuously, or all the time

[By the hour](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/by-the-hour)

Comment: +1. Similar to "sat for hours on end" :https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sat+by+the+hour%2Csat+for+hours+on+end&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csat%20by%20the%20hour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csat%20for%20hours%20on%20end%3B%2Cc0